# sockets programming gfortran

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I want to be able to call networking functions in my Fortran application. My boss wants me to do everything in Fortran instead of using C and Fortran. We have already done a version of the application using PGI's Fortran compiler on Windows. We are moving it to Linux where we will probably use their compiler. Right now, I'm using gfortran.

I have created an interface for these networking calls, and everything compiles and links.  The code below is something similar to what I'm doing except the interfaces and constants are in a module.

```
PROGRAM MAIN

    INTEGER,PARAMETER  ::AF_INET = 2
    INTEGER,PARAMETER  ::SOCK_STREAM = 1
    INTEGER,PARAMETER  ::IPPROTO_TCP = 6

    INTERFACE
      FUNCTION socket(domain,type,protocol)
        INTEGER  ::socket,domain,type,protocol
      END FUNCTION
    END INTERFACE

    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)
    WRTIE(*,*)"Socket returned: ",sock

END PROGRAM
```

When I run the program, the socket function fails returning -1. I don't really know what's going on. I don't add any libraries on the command line so I'm guess it is linking with the default libraries correctly. I compile using

```
gfortran -o MAIN_PROGRAM MAIN_PROGRAM.f90 -fno-underscoring
```

Comment: Have you tried to check errno?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use of the ISO_C_Binding introduced in Fortran 2003 to access C library functionality, this is the cleanest and most portable option you have. The [Gfortran documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html#Interoperability-with-C) has some details on it, as any other vendor manual. There are also some projects aiming to implement interfaces to POSIX for Fortran 90: [fortranposix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fortranposix/) and [posix90](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/posix90/). But as I said a proper C-Binding interface using the F2003 capabilities is probably the cleanest option, see also the [fortranwiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/C+interoperability).

*Edit:*
Here is your code with the ISO-C-Binding glue added (tested with gfortran 4.4.5):

```
program testsocket
  use, intrinsic ::  iso_c_binding

  implicit none

  interface
    function socket(domain, type, protocol) bind(c, name="socket")
      use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
      integer(kind=c_int) :: socket
      integer(kind=c_int), value :: domain, type, protocol
    end function socket
  end interface

  integer :: sock

  sock = socket(2_c_int, 1_c_int, 6_c_int)

  write(*,*) "Socket returned: ", sock

end program testsocket
```

Comment: Ah! I see my problem. I'm passing the arguments using call by reference so socket() is not being called with valid options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess.  You're a graduate student in science or engineering (but not computer science or computer engineering) and your boss was born before 1950.  If so, I have stood in your shoes (except that in my case the requirement was to use Fortran 77).  I feel your pain.

As you probably know, Fortran does not use header files to prototype function calls in the same way C does.  You can call a Fortran function without the header, when the types of the arguments are not checked.

However, there is this trouble -- or there used to be this trouble, for my most recent experience is several years out of date.  Compared to C, GNU Fortran prepends a hidden underscore to the name of each function.  It also lower-cases the function name.

The `readelf -a` program can help you here.  Use it on the object file your Fortran compiler emits.  Look in the output for the `socket` symbol.  If my recollection is right, you'll see an `_socket` in there.

If you really, really cannot use any C at all -- even to make a wrapper function with the C name `_socket()` -- then I admit that I do not know what you should do next.  In that case, you may be stuck in a tight spot.  Either way, good luck.

*Update:*  I recommend @M.S.B.'s comment below.

Comment: You can take control of the naming of functions with the ISO C Binding described by haraldki and avoid the underscores.   Mixing Fortran and C is much easier and more portable than it used to be.

Comment: I was born 1982 and I ise Fortran for new projects. I even translated a lot of code from C. I something bad with me?

Comment: @VladimirF:  No, nothing bad, of course.  Fortran is a tool to do a job, and you're using it to do the job.  Good for you.  If you want to know, my experience was the reverse.  I was required to use Fortran 77 (not even modern Fortran) for purposes for which C or even Perl was better suited.  I didn't mind.  I got paid, and I never argued with my boss about it; but, if you asked me whether I think that my boss made the right choice in this instance, I would say that I do not think so.  As for you:  go Fortran!